# Pressure produced by blowing with mouth

Tags: human-physiology, safety

I need some figures on the pressure humans are capable blowing with their mouth with zero flow. I only need very approximate figures. I'm guessing around 500mm of water? I haven't got a tube handy to try it out.

I've heard that it can also cause damage, eg playing wind instruments has been show to increase health risks due to inter-occular pressure. Any figures on what an acceptable level would be for someone repeatedly blowing for a profession?

Comment: Can you add references to "playing wind instruments has been show to increase health risks due to inter-occular pressure"?